# How do I draw arrows between column vectors?

Tags: vector

[image]

I want to draw lines/arrows representing equal values in these vector entries. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun an idea using Mathcha.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\longminus}{\scalebox{2.5}[2.0]{$-$}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}\bigtimes\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix}\longminus\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{pmatrix}\bigtimes\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\end{pmatrix}\raisebox{-1.1 em}{
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw    (220.8,175.4) -- (180,175.4) ;
\draw    (179,154) -- (221.8,196.8) ; 
\draw    (218.5,153.6) -- (181.5,195.4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\\b_5\end{pmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

`MWE` with `newtxtext, newtxmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\longminus}{\scalebox{2.5}[2.0]{$-$}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}\bigtimes\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix}\longminus\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{pmatrix}\bigtimes\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\end{pmatrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\end{pmatrix}\raisebox{-1.1 em}{
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw    (220.8,175.4) -- (180,175.4) ;
\draw    (179,154) -- (221.8,196.8) ; 
\draw    (218.5,153.6) -- (181.5,195.4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\\b_5\end{pmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]